# Explaining the zeroes of $x+\exp x$

Tags: calculus, analysis, exponential-function, roots

I want to know how can I explain why the function $x+ \exp x$ has a zero in $\mathbb{R}$? Where the equation $x+e^x=0$ can also be rewritten as $x=-e^x$

If anyone knows anything on how to begin such an explanation I will be very grateful!

For anyone wondering this was given to me by an upper classmate because I was interested in what they are learning, I don’t know the original source.

Comment: You've given this some thought?

Comment: Hint: just study the derivative, it is of constant sign... Then it is IVT.

Comment: The function is continuous, and it goes to $+ \infty $ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $- \infty$ as $x \rightarrow - \infty$. Does this help?

Comment: But what does it mean has a 0 in R? Is the x 0?

Comment: Because $f(x)=e^x+x$ is continous and because of $f(-1)<0$ and $f(0)>0$ , there exists a real number $u$ with $f(u)=0$. Because of $f'(x)=e^x+1>0$ for all $x$ , $u$ is moreover unique. The numerical value is $$u=-0.5671432904\cdots $$

Comment: Please add context to your answer, like where you got it from. This way it will be easier for other users to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the function $x+e^x$ is positive for infinitely many values. Now we need to show that it decreases as $x\rightarrow\infty$. Since we know that $x+e^x$ is continuous, it suffices to find one negative value. Take $e^{-1}-1$. Since $e^{-1}<1$, then this is negative, and so the function becomes negative. But since the function is continuous and is negative and positive at some values, it must intersect the $x$-axis, and so $x+e^x$ has a zero. When we have a $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ it means that the function has a zero if its domain and range are restricted to the real numbers.

Comment: Please do not answer a contextless question !

Comment: @Peter I will inform the OP

Comment: @Kamal Saleh thank you so much for the explanation, I finally understand it!

Comment: @gediroam No problem ;) Do you understand Calculus? Maybe someone could answer your question with it. But add context to your question first (Like where it came from) so that people will be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Peter the OP has changed. If you downvoted my answer (I'm suspecting you did, but there is nothing wrong about that), then there is no reason to keep it now ;)